# pip install chatterbot fails on windows

Tags: python, chatterbot

pip install chatterbot failing on windows - fresh install of python 3.8

```
command: 'c:\python38\python.exe' 'c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-1rlap7p2\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0'
```

Full Log

```
Collecting chatterbot
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6c/0e/dac0d82f34f86bf509cf5ef3e2dfc5aa7d444bd843a2330ceb7d854f84f2/ChatterBot-1.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pint>=0.8.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/15/9d/bf177ebbc57d25e9e296addc14a1303d1e34d7964af5df428a8332349c42/Pint-0.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pytz
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e7/f9/f0b53f88060247251bf481fa6ea62cd0d25bf1b11a87888e53ce5b7c8ad2/pytz-2019.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting spacy<2.2,>=2.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1f/e2/46650d03c7ff2b57ed7af211d41c3f606540f7adea92b5af65fcf9f605c0/spacy-2.1.9.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\python38\python.exe' 'c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-1rlap7p2\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (119 lines):
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/54/28/c45d8b54c1339f9644b87663945e54a8503cfef59cf0f65b3ff5dd17cf64/setuptools-42.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting wheel<0.33.0,>0.32.0
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ff/47/1dfa4795e24fd6f93d5d58602dd716c3f101cfd5a77cd9acbe519b44a0a9/wheel-0.32.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting Cython
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/22/03/510503cfbf20f62810a9548c9be13ab86181f00cca9a3a56717c4595d952/Cython-0.29.14-cp38-cp38-win32.whl
  Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ce/8d/d095bbb109a004351c85c83bc853782fc27692693b305dd7b170c36a1262/cymem-2.0.3.tar.gz
  Collecting preshed<2.1.0,>=2.0.1
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0b/14/c9aa735cb9c131545fc9e23031baccb87041ac9215b3d75f99e3cf18f6a3/preshed-2.0.1.tar.gz
  Collecting murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/22/e9/411be1845f1ac07ae3bc40a4b19ba401819baed4fa63b4f5ef28b2300eb4/murmurhash-1.0.2.tar.gz
  Collecting thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/92/39/ea2a3d5b87fd52fc865fd1ceb7b91dca1f85e227d53e7a086d260f6bcb93/thinc-7.0.8.tar.gz
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\python38\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Carlos\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wahyslx5\\thinc\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Carlos\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wahyslx5\\thinc\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wahyslx5\thinc\pip-egg-info'
           cwd: C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wahyslx5\thinc\
      Complete output (99 lines):
      Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
      Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6btuo9sq\numpy-1.18.0\tools\cythonize.py", line 61, in process_pyx
          from Cython.Compiler.Version import version as cython_version
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'

      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6btuo9sq\numpy-1.18.0\tools\cythonize.py", line 238, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6btuo9sq\numpy-1.18.0\tools\cythonize.py", line 234, in main
          find_process_files(root_dir)
        File "C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6btuo9sq\numpy-1.18.0\tools\cythonize.py", line 225, in find_process_files
          process(root_dir, fromfile, tofile, function, hash_db)
        File "C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6btuo9sq\numpy-1.18.0\tools\cythonize.py", line 191, in process
          processor_function(fromfile, tofile)
        File "C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6btuo9sq\numpy-1.18.0\tools\cythonize.py", line 66, in process_pyx
          raise OSError('Cython needs to be installed in Python as a module')
      OSError: Cython needs to be installed in Python as a module
      Running from numpy source directory.
      C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6btuo9sq\numpy-1.18.0\setup.py:425: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
        run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
          yield saved
        File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
          yield
        File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
          _execfile(setup_script, ns)
        File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
          exec(code, globals, locals)
        File "C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6btuo9sq\numpy-1.18.0\setup.py", line 450, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6btuo9sq\numpy-1.18.0\setup.py", line 433, in setup_package
        File "C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6btuo9sq\numpy-1.18.0\setup.py", line 240, in generate_cython
          "Environment :: Console",
      RuntimeError: Running cythonize failed!

      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wahyslx5\thinc\setup.py", line 261, in <module>
          setup_package()
        File "C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wahyslx5\thinc\setup.py", line 201, in setup_package
          setup(
        File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
          _install_setup_requires(attrs)
        File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 139, in _install_setup_requires
          dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
        File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 716, in fetch_build_eggs
          resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
        File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 780, in resolve
          dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
        File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1065, in best_match
          return self.obtain(req, installer)
        File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1077, in obtain
          return installer(requirement)
        File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 786, in fetch_build_egg
          return cmd.easy_install(req)
        File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 679, in easy_install
          return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
        File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 705, in install_item
          dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
        File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 890, in install_eggs
          return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
        File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1158, in build_and_install
          self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
        File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1144, in run_setup
          run_setup(setup_script, args)
        File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 253, in run_setup
          raise
        File "c:\python38\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
          self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
        File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
          yield
        File "c:\python38\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
          self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
        File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
          saved_exc.resume()
        File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
          six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
        File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\six.py", line 685, in reraise
          raise value.with_traceback(tb)
        File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
          yield saved
        File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
          yield
        File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
          _execfile(setup_script, ns)
        File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
          exec(code, globals, locals)
        File "C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6btuo9sq\numpy-1.18.0\setup.py", line 450, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6btuo9sq\numpy-1.18.0\setup.py", line 433, in setup_package
        File "C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-6btuo9sq\numpy-1.18.0\setup.py", line 240, in generate_cython
          "Environment :: Console",
      RuntimeError: Running cythonize failed!
      Cythonizing sources
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python38\python.exe' 'c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-1rlap7p2\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working - uninstalled all pythons, cleared caches, installed python 3.7.2.

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:** Chatterbot is indirectly using blis 0.2.4 And that version is not providing precompiled wheels for python 3.8.

**To fix that issue:**

- Uninstall the current python version;  check the version type in cmd `python --version`
- [Download and install python 3.7](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/python-3.7.0-amd64.exe)
- Then install chatterbot `pip install chatterbot`